# Disc to left of list item is displayed at bottom

Tags: html, css

Screenshot of what is happening:

[image: Screen shot 2010-07-27 at 3.37.23 PM.png]

It is just a list item within an underordered list, this is happening in IE7 and nowhere else.

```
<ul>
  <li>Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text.</li>
</ul>

.fancybox-entry.computer-policy li {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.fancybox-entry.computer-policy ul + p {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.fancybox-entry.computer-policy ul {
    margin:5px 0 10px 25px;
}
```

Any help as to why it is doing that and a fix is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong! or maybe I just didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is that the bullets on the list-items are appearing at the vertical bottom of the line as opposed to the top.

Comment: I had a similar problem with bullets but this question's answer didn't help me. See my question for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735404/listitem-disc-displaying-at-vertical-bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the width CSS property triggers hasLayout for the `li` element in IE7. First try removing the `width:100%;` declaration to make sure the bullet appears in the correct place. If you can't do without the width property, you can use `position: relative;` and `vertical-align: top;` to move the bullet back into place, as outlined at http://www.gunlaug.no/tos/moa_26.html.

Note that the code on that page uses hacks to target IE6 and IE7. I recommend using conditional comments instead, like so:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    /* IE7-specific CSS here */
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1 Good call on the hasLayout, it's a tricky problem to catch if you don't know what causes it

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is still too low to comment, otherwise I would have added this to peterjmag's answer. (Maybe he can include it...)

The width property is the culprit, but I would suggest a different change. To make sure your list elements take up full-width in IE7, use "width:auto" instead. This will give you the same look and your bullet points will take their proper place. I have found that "vertical-align:top/text-top" pushes the bullet points just a little north of where I would like them.

If you don't have conditional classes or an IE stylesheet, just use "*width:auto" to target IE7.